# get model data from a folder outside of the cakePHP app folder

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a site where the directories are set up like this

```
public_html/framework/cake
public_html/framework/app
public_html/index.php
public_html/contact.php
public_html/aboutus.php
```

Is there any way to get variables or model data from `public_html/framework/app` when a user navigates to `public_html/aboutus.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the [HttpSocket documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1517/HttpSocket).

An example implementation would look similar to:

```
/**
 * import HttpSocket class
 */
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');

/**
 * instantiate and make a POST request to http://localhost/contact.php
 * sending var1 => test
 */
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$HttpSocket->post('http://localhost/contact.php', array(
  array('var1' => 'test')
));

/**
 * response
 */
$response = $HttpSocket->response;
```

Comment: Moz, this looks like it might be what I need but how do I echo the results in contact.php? If I browse to contact.php from my browser, will I be able to see data from my cake app?

Comment: Your contact.php would process the data you sent to it - available in $_POST. So for example, it might store the data in a database or send an email. Actually browsing to contact.php might display a contact form (or nothing, it's up to you)

Comment: but I need the data the other way around. I don't need to post to cake from contact.php I simply want to display some text when the user browses to contact.php that says "This is the contact page", and that text is stored in my cake database.

Comment: You just need to create a database connection, a sql query to get the content and then display it. Your question originally asked "Is there any way to send variables or model data from public_html/framework/app to public_html/aboutus.php?"

Comment: You're right. The title is misleading, I will change it. So is there a way to retrieve Model data in contact.php. I'm trying to avoid creating the files to connect to the database and use cake instead... It's just that the cake folder is in the wrong place in relation to contact.php.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't move your contact form into your Cake project? In answer to you question about getting model data from you Cake project: It could be done. You would have a create a service in your Cake project that could be called to return the data.

Comment: Well, I was just trying to simplify the question. The site is pretty large and I am trying to find the easiest way to retrieve records from the database without migrating all the files to the app folder.